# Elements Extend Beyond Page

Tags: html, css, border, padding, margins

I'm moving some elements around on my site and have found that two of them are invisibly extending well beyond the right edge of the page. The site is www.abadcaseofthedates.com and the two elements are above the fold: HTML8 (site search) and ArchiveList (the pull-down archive menu). I realize that they're likely extending this far as a result of them being children of column-center-inner, but I can't figure out how to downsize the extensions of these two elements (but not everything else in column-center-inner) off the side of the page.

[image]
[image]

HTML8:

```
<div class="widget HTML" id="HTML8">
<h2 class="title">Search Site</h2>
<div class="widget-content">
<form action="http://www.google.com" id="cse-search-box" target="_blank" _lpchecked="1">
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-8645914820193959:3645685348">
    <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8">
    <input type="text" name="q" size="25" style="background-image: url(https://www.google.com/cse/static/en/google_custom_search_watermark.gif); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-position: 0% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">
    <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search">
  </div>
<input name="siteurl" type="hidden" value="www.abadcaseofthedates.com/">    <input name="ref" type="hidden" value="www.abadcaseofthedates.com/"><input name="ss" type="hidden" value=""></form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=en"></script>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<span class="widget-item-control">
<span class="item-control blog-admin">
<a class="quickedit" href="//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=3186499665856075184&amp;widgetType=HTML&amp;widgetId=HTML8&amp;action=editWidget&amp;sectionId=main" onclick="return _WidgetManager._PopupConfig(document.getElementById(&quot;HTML8&quot;));" target="configHTML8" title="Edit">
<img alt="" height="18" src="//img1.blogblog.com/img/icon18_wrench_allbkg.png" width="18">
</a>
</span>
</span>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

HTML8 CSS:

```
#HTML8 {
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
top: 65px;
left: 400px;
}
```

BlogArchive1:

```
<div class="widget BlogArchive" id="BlogArchive1">
<div class="widget-content">
<div id="ArchiveList">
<div id="BlogArchive1_ArchiveList">
<select id="BlogArchive1_ArchiveMenu">
<option value="">
</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2015_11_01_archive.html">November 2015 (1)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2015_10_01_archive.html">October 2015 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2015_09_01_archive.html">September 2015 (30)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2015_08_01_archive.html">August 2015 (32)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2015_07_01_archive.html">July 2015 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2015_06_01_archive.html">June 2015 (30)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2015_05_01_archive.html">May 2015 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2015_04_01_archive.html">April 2015 (30)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2015_03_01_archive.html">March 2015 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2015_02_01_archive.html">February 2015 (28)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2015_01_01_archive.html">January 2015 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2014_12_01_archive.html">December 2014 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2014_11_01_archive.html">November 2014 (30)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2014_10_01_archive.html">October 2014 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2014_09_01_archive.html">September 2014 (30)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2014_08_01_archive.html">August 2014 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2014_07_01_archive.html">July 2014 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2014_06_01_archive.html">June 2014 (32)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2014_05_01_archive.html">May 2014 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2014_04_01_archive.html">April 2014 (30)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2014_03_01_archive.html">March 2014 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2014_02_01_archive.html">February 2014 (32)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2014_01_01_archive.html">January 2014 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2013_12_01_archive.html">December 2013 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2013_11_01_archive.html">November 2013 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2013_10_01_archive.html">October 2013 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2013_09_01_archive.html">September 2013 (30)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2013_08_01_archive.html">August 2013 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2013_07_01_archive.html">July 2013 (35)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2013_06_01_archive.html">June 2013 (38)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2013_05_01_archive.html">May 2013 (33)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2013_04_01_archive.html">April 2013 (30)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2013_03_01_archive.html">March 2013 (33)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2013_02_01_archive.html">February 2013 (33)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2013_01_01_archive.html">January 2013 (39)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2012_12_01_archive.html">December 2012 (33)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2012_11_01_archive.html">November 2012 (30)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2012_10_01_archive.html">October 2012 (35)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2012_09_01_archive.html">September 2012 (32)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2012_08_01_archive.html">August 2012 (32)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2012_07_01_archive.html">July 2012 (32)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2012_06_01_archive.html">June 2012 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2012_05_01_archive.html">May 2012 (34)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2012_04_01_archive.html">April 2012 (33)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2012_03_01_archive.html">March 2012 (45)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2012_02_01_archive.html">February 2012 (69)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2012_01_01_archive.html">January 2012 (90)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2011_12_01_archive.html">December 2011 (98)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2011_11_01_archive.html">November 2011 (92)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2011_10_01_archive.html">October 2011 (103)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2011_09_01_archive.html">September 2011 (102)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2011_08_01_archive.html">August 2011 (112)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2011_07_01_archive.html">July 2011 (97)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2011_06_01_archive.html">June 2011 (75)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2011_05_01_archive.html">May 2011 (117)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2011_04_01_archive.html">April 2011 (160)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2011_03_01_archive.html">March 2011 (184)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2011_02_01_archive.html">February 2011 (160)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2011_01_01_archive.html">January 2011 (130)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2010_12_01_archive.html">December 2010 (99)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2010_11_01_archive.html">November 2010 (70)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2010_10_01_archive.html">October 2010 (45)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2010_09_01_archive.html">September 2010 (32)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2010_08_01_archive.html">August 2010 (31)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2010_07_01_archive.html">July 2010 (32)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2010_06_01_archive.html">June 2010 (38)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2010_05_01_archive.html">May 2010 (39)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2010_04_01_archive.html">April 2010 (47)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2010_03_01_archive.html">March 2010 (60)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2010_02_01_archive.html">February 2010 (57)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2010_01_01_archive.html">January 2010 (63)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2009_12_01_archive.html">December 2009 (67)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2009_11_01_archive.html">November 2009 (76)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2009_10_01_archive.html">October 2009 (84)</option>
<option value="http://www.abadcaseofthedates.com/2009_09_01_archive.html">September 2009 (85)</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<span class="widget-item-control">
<span class="item-control blog-admin">
<a class="quickedit" href="//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=3186499665856075184&amp;widgetType=BlogArchive&amp;widgetId=BlogArchive1&amp;action=editWidget&amp;sectionId=main" onclick="return _WidgetManager._PopupConfig(document.getElementById(&quot;BlogArchive1&quot;));" target="configBlogArchive1" title="Edit">
<img alt="" height="18" src="//img1.blogblog.com/img/icon18_wrench_allbkg.png" width="18">
</a>
</span>
</span>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Blog Archive CSS:

```
#ArchiveList {
position: relative;
bottom: 1px;
left: 350px;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is your element is inside of your anchor tag. When you are trying to click it you are getting the same effect that you desire on the previous element in the DOM. I can't really tell what is going on with your date picker, but if you post your code I'm sure we can figure it out!

this will fix the side scrolling --

CSS:

```
html {
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I really appreciate your help. Bear in mind that I'm still learning as I'm going along, but I appreciate your patience. How much of the code would you need to see? I can post all of it or some, but what would be the most helpful?

Comment: They work, but they extend beyond the edge of the page. The page can scroll from side to side (which I don't want) because the elements invisibly extend beyond the right edge.

Comment: add overflow-x: hidden to your CSS. This will eliminate the side scrolling

Comment: Tried that:

    #HTML8 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    top: 65px;
    left: 400px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #HTML8 .title {
    overflow-x: hidden
    }

    #HTML8 #cse-search-box {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }

Maybe I'm adding it to the wrong place?

Comment: use exactly what I gave you. Don't apply it to your div, but to the entire page. instead of #HTML8 use -- html { overflow-x: hidden; }

Comment: Just tried your html {} CSS above. Still side scrolling.

Comment: i added it through the web browser and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm on the site in Safari and it's still allowing me to scroll to the right.

Comment: safari! I was in Chrome! Change the width of the div that the google search input is in to 300px.

Comment: Tried it in the HTML, tried it in the CSS. Still not working. Must be something more I'm missing. I have a feeling it's related to the fact that it's under the auspices of column-center-inner... thoughts?

Comment: There is a lot going on with that element. From what I see it is nested fairly deep. I had to change multiple element widths.

Comment: I fixed it. I moved the HTML8 and Archive under column-left-inner (as opposed to where they were under column-center-inner) and adjusted the positions from there. Thanks for your help all the same! I appreciate you showing me the overflow-x CSS. I'm sure it'll be helpful at some point.